# Using a loop to combine multiple arrays into an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I have made an object prototype for which I want to combine a set of arrays to create under said object.

I've tried making the object prototype with a function contructor with the needed properties as parameters. Then I created arrays with the data for all the properties. My problem is that when I create a loop my first idea was to create a variable and name it after the item relevant for each object instance (In this case the name of the football player), but dynamic variable naming is not possible, so I cannot seem to create multiple variables / object instances in a loop.

```
var Players = function(name, position, number, yearOfBirth) {
this.name = name;
this.position = position;
this.number = number;
this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
}

var playerNames = ['1','2',....'25'];
var playerPosition = [....];
var playerNumber = [....];
var playerYearOfBirth = [....];

for (var i = 0; i < playerNames.length; i++) {
    var playerNames[i] = new Object(playerNames[i], playerPosition[i], playerNumber[i], 
    playerYearOfBirth[i]);
}
```

So this of course doesn't work, so I also tried this.

```
var player = [];
for (var i = 0; i < playerNames.length; i++) {
  var players = {}
  player.name = playerNames[i];
  player.position = playerPosition[i];
  player.number = playerNumber[i];
  player.yearOfBirth = playerYearOfBirth[i]
  player.push(players[i]);
}
```

but this only applies data to the last object.

So I expected my output to be that it filled in all the objects with the right data, but I wonder if I'm trying to create an unneccesary solution. I haven't played around with objects before, so I'm just trying to get around it and see how it is applied outside of tutorials, when I actually have a usecase for it.

Comment: Remove the `var`, replace `Object` with `Player`, then it sould work

Comment: Looks like you confused players and player?

Comment: "but this only applies data to the last object." you mixed up `player` and `players`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The array and the object were used in place of each other thus giving error

```js
var players = [];
playerNames=[1,2]
playerPosition=[1,2]
playerNumber=[1,2]
playerYearOfBirth=[1,2]

for (var i = 0; i < playerNames.length; i++) {
  var player = {}
  player.name = playerNames[i];
  player.position = playerPosition[i];
  player.number = playerNumber[i];
  player.yearOfBirth = playerYearOfBirth[i]
  players.push(player);
}
console.log(players)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var players = []; // the list of the players
for (var i = 0; i < playerNames.length; i++) {
  var player = {} // the object player
  player.name = playerNames[i];
  player.position = playerPosition[i];
  player.number = playerNumber[i];
  player.yearOfBirth = playerYearOfBirth[i]
  players.push(player); // add the object player into the list of players
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor only represents the information about one player, so rename that to `Player`. You can then set up a new `players` array to which you can `push` new players as they are created.

```js
function Player(name, position, number, yearOfBirth) {
  this.name = name;
  this.position = position;
  this.number = number;
  this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
}

const players = [];

const playerNames = ['Bob', 'Sue'];
const playerPosition = [1, 12];
const playerNumber = ['Forward', 'Goal'];
const playerYearOfBirth = [1972, 1956];

for (var i = 0; i < playerNames.length; i++) {
  const player = new Player(playerNames[i], playerPosition[i], playerNumber[i], playerYearOfBirth[i]);
  players.push(player);
}

console.log(players);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could collect all players in an object and access the player by the name.

```js
function Player(name, position, number, yearOfBirth) {
    this.name = name;
    this.position = position;
    this.number = number;
    this.yearOfBirth = yearOfBirth;
}

var playerNames = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'],
    playerPosition = [3, 2, 1],
    playerNumber = [10, 11, 12],
    playerYearOfBirth = [2000, 1998, 1999],
    players = {};

for (var i = 0; i < playerNames.length; i++) {
    players[playerNames[i]] = new Player(
        playerNames[i],
        playerPosition[i],
        playerNumber[i],
        playerYearOfBirth[i]
    );
}

console.log(players);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I'll try this out as well. Thank you!